# Convert RGB 5551 bitmap to RGB 565 bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface, rgb, rgba

I need to show an image coming in a byte buffer from cpp layer and passed to android layer to show in a bitmap as image. The bitmap coming from cpp layer is encoded in RGBA 5551.
When i outputs the image to RGB 565 in android side but the image is appearing a blue shade due to incompatibility.

Is there any way to convert the RGBA 5551 to android compatible format. Also thought of using OpenGL but still having little idea in that :).

Comment: The title of your question seems to be the opposite of what you're describing in the body. Do you need 565 to 5551, or 5551 to 565? It would be helpful if you could edit the title/question to make it consistent.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks for pointing out this. Title updated.